# How to post to Chatter Answers Community using code

Tags: apex, visualforce, connect-api, chatter-answers

I'm building a custom look/feel for Chatter Answers Community by pulling questions and replies and I'm now at a point where I have to implement users posting replies on this custom front-end I've created with apex/visualforce code. Is there a way I can do this through Apex?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Connect API` provided by Salesforce to customize the chatter feed through Apex and VisualForce. These apex classes give you access to chatter in through apex in much the same way as the REST API allowing you to create and customize your own chatter feeds and create chatter posts. Please follow [this link](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2014/01/chatter-apex/) written by Bryan Leboff for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I found this article before when researching this, but I don't think it applies to Questions/Replies sObjects, because my posts don't show up in the Feed/FeedItem in the Schema.

Comment: You're right, Chatter Answers isn't the same as the Chatter feed (this is confusing!) and so the ConnectApi classes can't be used. Does it work if you Create a new Question like you would create any other sObject? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm#apex_dml_section